# How to hide cell output in jupyter notebooks (VSCode + Python Extension)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I use version 1.38 of VSCode in combination with the python extension (ms-python.python) to be able to modify jupyter notebooks inside of VSCode. Is there any option to hide the output of specific cells (e.g. when plotting multiple plots in one cell)?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Bumped into the same problem today.
It seems to be that the shortcuts from jupyter notebook are integrated into the jupyter notebook in visual studio code. 
If you press "o" on a cell, it will hide the cell output.

Comment: What is the key to hide the cell input?

Comment: Ah, there's a keyboard shortcut for this. I was thinking this function didn't exist in VS Code at the time because you don't seem to be able to double/triple click on a cell to toggle between these state. Thanks!

Comment: Whats the key to unhide it?

Comment: @Sam It's a toggle. Pressing "o" when the cell is highlighted hides and unhides

Comment: Fn + O works on my windows laptop.

Answer (score 9):

Put this as the first line of your cell.

```
%%capture 
#Then the rest of your code in the cell...
```

The output from that cell won't be printed inside the notebook.

Comment: Best Answer. I wanted to run from notebook1 another notebook2 and transfer data frame from notbook2 to notebook1. I tried soooo many options all did not work. This was the best answer. Here is my code in notebook1: 
  %%capture             # to supress output of the cell;

  %run -n ./notebook2.ipynb  # run notbook2;

  df = DFF()               # function in notebook2 that returns a dataframe after doing all work

Answer (score 3):

Seems like there's no option for that at the moment. 
The official document here doesn't mention that.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support

Comment: Okay, I didn't find it there either. Hopefully they will add this option in one of the next releases of VSCode/the python extension.

Answer (score 0):

Add the entire code or the part you need to the keybindings.json file:

```
{ // To collapse active cell input
    "key": "ctrl+[",
    "command": "notebook.cell.collapseCellInput",
    "when": "notebookCellListFocused && !inputFocus && !notebookCellInputIsCollapsed"
},
{ // To expand active cell input
    "key": "ctrl+[",
    "command": "notebook.cell.expandCellInput",
    "when": "notebookCellInputIsCollapsed && notebookCellListFocused"
},
{ //To collapse active cell output
    "key": "ctrl+]",
    "command": "notebook.cell.collapseCellOutput",
    "when": "notebookCellHasOutputs && notebookCellListFocused && !inputFocus && !notebookCellOutputIsCollapsed"
},
{ // To expand active cell output
    "key": "ctrl+]",
    "command": "notebook.cell.expandCellOutput",
    "when": "notebookCellListFocused && notebookCellOutputIsCollapsed"
},
{ // To collapse all cell inputs
    "key": "ctrl+shift+[",
    "command": "notebook.cell.collapseAllCellInputs"
},
{ // To expand all cell inputs
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+[",
    "command": "notebook.cell.expandAllCellInputs"
},
{ // To collapse all cell outputs
    "key": "ctrl+shift+]",
    "command": "notebook.cell.collapseAllCellOutputs"
},
{ // To expand all cell outputs
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+]",
    "command": "notebook.cell.expandAllCellOutputs"
}
```

Change key combinations as you wish.